# Use specific month and quarter column headers

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi, ssas

I would like to be able to make a report with the following column headers:

```
   - month_10_past_year 
   - month_11_past_year 
   - month_12_past_year
   - quarter_1_past_year 
   - quarter_2_past_year 
   - quarter_3_past_year
   - quarter_4_past_year 
   - quarter_4_current_year 
   - month_12_current_year
   - month_11_current_year 
   - month_11_past_year
```

I have a financial FACT and a generic DIMENSION with dates. I would like to use Power BI.

I have been trying and found no other way than just start with all columns and then hiding the ones I do not need. This is workable, but butt-ugly and I can foresee serious performance issues.

What would be the most efficient way to get this done?

Addition 1: *To create the report I need to work with existing cubes which do not perform optimal. I did some testing and performance is poor, especially when all columns are used. Since there is an option to add (not change) in the cubes, I hope there is a simple/regular solution like a view or dimension. After all, this is something I have seen before in financial reports. Beautiful reports... Which I did not make.*

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: If all columns are *potentially* needed, then it makes sense to do what you've already done, which is generate all columns in a single query or view (since the logic for all columns is likely to be highly similar), then selectively hide any unused columns, or omit them from selection in any query which calls the view (and in this latter case, the database will usually respond by completely excluding from execution, the logic which generates the unused columns).